# Convert string to bytes then write to file

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I'm trying to convert a string to bytes, then write results to a text file, but it just keeps writing the plain text string & not the bytes..

Example code -

```
//private void Save(String file, String input)

byte[] array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

using(StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(file))
{
    writer.BaseStream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
}
```

Executed using -

```
String data = "HELLO";
Save("File.txt", data);
```

Comment: Text (characters) are bytes... do you mean you want to convert the text into some sort of hex notation?

Comment: please show us what you input looks like and what kind of output you do expect. but i guess looking at the bitconverter class should solve your issue! https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: :) you write bytes `72 69 76 76 79` to file, then open that file in notepad, which in turn translate this bytes sequence to UTF8 text _"HELLO"_. Try to `File.ReadAllBytes(file)` and you will see `72 69 76 76 79`, then try to `File.ReadAllText(file)` and you will see `HELLO`.

Comment: text is bytes, thats how a computer stores information

Comment: If you want to write a *dump*, i.e. `"72 69 76 76 79"` text instead of `"Hello"` you can try Linq: `File.AppendAllText(file, string.Join(" ", input.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("x2"))));`

Comment: @R2-D2 technically you always store any information in bytes. It all depends on how you use it. When you load `72 69 76 76 79` to notepad - notepad pretend it to be an UTF8 text sequence - so it decode it and show you _"HELLO"_ but this is still `72 69 76 76 79`.

Comment: @Vasily.sib yeah I wanted the byte values to display in notepad, but I've found a work around though. Thanks for your input & help in leading me to finding a solution :).